# How to set a HTTP_Exception_404

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.2

I am using kohana 3.2 and kohana-error module is working fine, when the page does not exist.
But I have this situation:  the page exist, but no data is coming, because the data does not exist. I am using the route param to check de database.

So I did this,

```
if($response )
    {
       return $response; 
    } else {
       throw new HTTP_Exception_404('Page Not Found');
    }
```

If there are data return, if not, create a ‘Page Not Found’ and I supose it will be caught by the kohana-error module but it is not....
Is that possible? Is this the right approach?

Comment: Hmm.. maybe you have to set `Kohana::$environment` to Production?

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.php`, you do the following:

```php
$request = Request::factory();

try
{
  $response = $request->execute();

  if (!$response->body())
  {
    throw new HTTP_Exception_404();
  }
}
catch (Exception $exc)
{
   if ($exc instanceof HTTP_Exception_404)
   {
      $response = Request::factory('your/404error/controller')->execute();
   }
   else
   {
      // rethrow exception
      throw $exc;
   }
}

echo
  $response
  ->send_headers()
  ->body();
```

That way, you can execute a controller for each HTTP exception, or you can use a catch all 404 page for all exceptions (50x and 40x errors)